# C++ template type_trait enable_if a class is a map

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, decltype, enable-if

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// enable_if_t = MapType implements .find(KeyType key), .begin(), .end(), and .begin() 
// and MapType::iterator it has it->first and it->second
template<typename MapType>
decltype(declval<MapType>().begin()->second) MapGetOrDefault(
    MapType mymap, 
    decltype(declval<MapType>().begin()->first) key, 
    decltype(declval<MapType>().begin()->second) defaultValue = decltype(declval<MapType>().begin()->second){}
    )
{
    auto it = mymap.find(key);
    if (it!=mymap.end()) return it->second;
    else return defaultValue;
}

int main()
{   
    map<string, int> a;
    unordered_map<int, string> b;
    
    a["1"] = 2;
    cout << MapGetOrDefault(a, "1") << " " << MapGetOrDefault(a, "2") << " " << MapGetOrDefault(a, "2", -1) << "\n";

    b[1] = "hello";
    cout << MapGetOrDefault(b, 1) << " " << MapGetOrDefault(b, 2) << " " << MapGetOrDefault(b, 3, "world") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a generic `get_or_default()` function that can be used with all types of map. There are 4 conditions that a class must meet to be counted as map, like shown in the code comment.

How can I do this using C++ type traits? Also, how to change `decltype(declval<MapType>().begin()->first)` into something more clean?

Edit: is `enable_if_t` even needed in this case? My goal is to just prevent compilation

Comment: you don't really need SFINAE when there is no other overload to pick. Your `MapGetOrDefault` will already fail when `MapType` has no `find`, `end` and its iterators have no `second`

Comment: in other words: What do you want to happen when `MapType` does not meet the conditions?

Comment: In case SFINAE isn't necessary, how can I remove decltype(...) with something cleaner?

Comment: you can remove it alltogether. The only reason to keep it or replace it with something else would be to get a little nicer error message

Comment: oh sorry, I think I misread the question. You are looking for a nicer way to write the return type, right? SFINAE wasnt the intention here, sorry ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number actually I was thinking about SFINAE, but if it's isn't necessary then the other question (nicer way to write the function) remains :D

Comment: I just got confused by the `enable_if` in the comment and then didnt read careful enough. I already added it in a PS, but don't miss to change the arugment to a reference to not make a unencessary copy

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number forgot to add const ref, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps have member aliases `mapped_type` and `key_type` (and `value_type`) that you can use :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename MapType>
typename MapType::mapped_type MapGetOrDefault(
    MapType mymap, 
    typename MapType::key_type key, 
    typename MapType::mapped_type defaultValue = typename MapType::mapped_type{}
    )
{
    auto it = mymap.find(key);
    if (it!=mymap.end()) return it->second;
    else return defaultValue;
}

int main()
{   
    map<string, int> a;
    unordered_map<int, string> b;
    
    a["1"] = 2;
    cout << MapGetOrDefault(a, "1") << " " << MapGetOrDefault(a, "2") << " " << MapGetOrDefault(a, "2", -1) << "\n";

    b[1] = "hello";
    cout << MapGetOrDefault(b, 1) << " " << MapGetOrDefault(b, 2) << " " << MapGetOrDefault(b, 3, "world") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Template aliases can help for more terse syntax:

```
template <typename T> using mapped_type = typename T::mapped_type;

template <typename T> using key_type = typename T::key_type;

template<typename MapType>
mapped_type<MapType> MapGetOrDefault(
    MapType mymap, 
    key_type<MapType> key, 
    mapped_type<MapType> defaultValue = mapped_type<MapType>{}
    )
{
    auto it = mymap.find(key);
    if (it!=mymap.end()) return it->second;
    else return defaultValue;
}
```

PS: I didnt change it because it wasn't part of the question, but you should not make a copy of the map when passing it to the function, rather use `const MapType& mymap` for the argument.

PPS: As mentioned by Caleth in a comment, with a transparent comparator, ie one that has a `Comparator::is_transparent` member type, you might want to support the overload (4) listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find by introducing another template argument `KeyType` that can be deduced from the `key` paramter.

Comment: Might not want exactly `typename MapType::key_type` if the map has a transparent compare

Comment: @Caleth I admit that I am not 100% sure what it means for a comparator to be transparent. As I understood it, it could be a type with a templated `operator()` that can accept a wide range of types (basically anything that can be compared to `key_type`). Anyhow, I tried to add it to the answer

Comment: basically if `typename MapType::key_compare::is_transparent` is a type, there are template overloads of `find` etc